# Any security or encryption with ODR content in iOS? (On-Demand Resources)

Tags: ios, drm, copy-protection, on-demand-resources

When using Apple’s On-Demand Resources (ODR) feature, is there any protection of the downloaded resources? Any [DRM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) features?

Are the downloaded files encrypted or otherwise protected from the prying eyes of someone examining the contents of the app on a Mac or PC?

Is there anything I can do to copy-protect the downloaded resources?

Comment: "the prying eyes of someone examining the contents of the app on a Mac or PC" Those prying eyes wouldn't find anything. ODR files are not placed inside the app (even though the API for access to them presents the illusion that that's where they are).

Comment: @matt So where are they stored? Are they securely hidden from prying eyes? Can you cite documentation?

Comment: Let me ask you this. Suppose your app, just in the normal way, downloads a file and then stores it in its Application Support sandbox directory (`.applicationSupportDirectory`). Is that "securely hidden from prying eyes"? (I use Application Support deliberately, because Documents can be downright public, depending on the app.) Well, ODR is no more or less so. Sandboxing is sandboxing. It is what it is.